# slice and remove from list in the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

When I do:

```
abc = [1,2,3,4,5]
dd = (abc[:]).remove(4)
print(dd)
print(abc)
```

the result is:

> None
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

But if I do:

```
abc = [1,2,3,4,5]
dd = abc[:]
dd.remove(4)
print(dd)
print(abc)
```

the result is:

> [1, 2, 3, 5]
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Can someone explain why these 2 things are different? I would think it would do the same.

Comment: `.remove()` modifies a list in place and returns `None` always. It's like doing `dd = print(abc)` the `print()` performs some action but returns `None` so your variable is going to be set to `None` always.

Comment: @Boris 
Right... Too many hours looking at the same thing and simple things stop being so simple. That's correct thanks

Comment: You can try to use Python Visualizer to investigate this behaviour yourself: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you put the return value of `.remove()` method in your `dd` variable, and the return value of this method is always `None`

---

```
abc = [1,2,3,4,5]
dd = abc[:]
rt_value = dd.remove(4)
print(rt_value)
print(dd)
print(abc)
```

will result

> None
> [1, 2, 3, 5]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

We can access a range of items in a list by using the slicing operator (colon).
Also, you can check https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html for better understanding.